# How to Save a TextField Content to a File in VB

Tags: file-io, vb6, evb

I'm trying to know how to save a content of a TextField to a File, like a *.txt*, using a **Common Dialog**, only a command dialog in *Visual Basic 6*, i need this using a only a common dialog, because i'm trying to do the same aplication in **eVB**, and eVB **does not support this methods**:

```
   Dim objFSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
   Dim objStream As Scripting.TextStream
```

Please help me, i'm needing this so much! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim fileHandle As File 
Set fileHandle = CreateObject("FILECTL.File")
fileHandle.Open "filename.txt", 2 
fileHandle.LinePrint "some text"
fileHandle.Close
Set fileHandle = Nothing
```

Comment: Also, eVB is more similar to VBS than VB5/6

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with eVB, but does it support legacy style file operations like this:

```
Open "filename.txt" for output as #1
Print #1, yourtextfield.text
Close #1
```

Comment: This appends an end of line to the text box contents. Fine if that's what you want - however you may not want this with a multi-line text-box, particularly if you are repeatedly loading and saving the file. Add a semicolon to the end of the Print line to avoid adding the end of line (line-feed and carriage-return).